# How do I wait inside a child process until the parent process reached a certain point?

Tags: c

**PSEUDO-CODE:**

```
Child:
...
wait until parent prints "blabla"
...

Parent:
...
print "blabla"
...
```

I can't use `wait`, because that would be the other way around and furthermore, I want to continue the parent process after the `print "blabla"` parallel to the child process.
 I could imagine to share with `mmap` a `pthread_mutex_t` variable and solve the issue with mutual exclusion, but I am not sure about that and wanted to ask if there might exists a very easy solution.

Comment: As you suspect, you need to use some form of `interprocess communication`.  Injecting a message into the child's standard input is often one of the simpler ones to set up and *fairly* portable.  But your question is really both too broad and too system dependent.

Comment: @ChrisStratton okay, I am going to overthink it, thank you. Gonna get some sleep now ^^'

Comment: Depends on how you created the child. If the child was created with `pthread_create`, then all you need is a `pthread_mutex_t`. There's no need for `mmap`.

Comment: If it was created with `pthread_create()` it's not a child *process* but rather a *thread*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Signals for this,
After completing a certain task parent process should send a signal to child process by using Kill system call and by updating the signal handler of the signal child process can do further task.

Child:
    signal_handler()
    {
    ...
    }
    main()
    {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    while(1);//wait until parent prints "blabla"
    }

```
Parent:
...
print "blabla"
 kill(pid_of_child,signal)
 ...
```

Comment: That's *possible* but it's probably not the best way.  Generally a signal would be used for something abnormal.

Comment: @ChrisStratton while true that that could be not the *best way*, it is simple and reasonable. Signals are often used for things that are not at all *abnormal*, see for example SIGWINCH https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGWINCH

Comment: This is going to be quite challenging to get right. If the parent sends the signal before the child is ready for it, the signal may get lost or cause mischief for the child.  To do this reliably, the parent would have to wait for a signal from the child that indicates that the child is ready to accept the signal from the parent, otherwise race conditions and unpredictable behavior could result. For this reason, a pipe or socketpair is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Have two global variables,one for mutex lock and another for a signal variable like this.

```
pthread_cond_t signal = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t cond_mutex = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

In your parent thread when you print blabla signal the child thread :

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mutex);
pthread_cond_signal(&signal);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mutex);
```

In your child thread wait for the signal :

```
struct timespec time_to_wait = {0, 0};
time_to_wait.tv_sec = time(NULL) + 10;//10 secs
pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mutex);
status = pthread_cond_timedwait(&signal,&cond_mutex, &time_to_wait);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mutex);
```

You can extend this code to handle repeatedly wait for the condition to occur for every 't' seconds within a loop, or simply wait once for 't' seconds and quit.
Refer this [doc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) for the return values.

Comment: Threads are all peers and don't have parent/child relationships. In any event, this question wasn't about threads at all anyway -- it was about processes (which do have parent/child relationships).